# Collision between blockUI and CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, blockui

I'm trying to use blockUI to create a login block effect, something like:

```
        $('#login-box-btn').click(function () {
            alert("haha");
            $.blockUI({
                message: $('#login-box'),
                css: {
                    margin: 0, border: 0,
                    textAlign: 'left'
                }
            });
            $('.blockOverlay').click($.unblockUI);
        });
```

Meanwhile, I want to use a replace a textarea by ckeditor on the same page, namely:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor-test');
```

And in html:

```
<textarea id="ckeditor-test"></textarea>
```

And the result is blockUI stops working! But jquery still works, as there will be an alert message "haha" shown. As I commented out `CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor-test');` ,however, blockUI back to live. I'm using CKEditor 4.02, and the newest version of blockUI. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vRV6S/

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. It must be something wrong with my django-ckeditor plugin.